# Why isn't this function closure working for google map api?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am making a page on which the google map will render with many markers. I want infowindow to show for each marker when clicked. For this, I had to add click event listener on each marker. Now since there can be hundreds of marker, I used a for loop. That is I have to add event listeners to hundreds of marker. For this I used the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Info windows</title>
  <style>
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    #first-tab {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 10px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: green;
    }
    #second-tab {
      position: absolute;
      top: 140px;
      left: 10px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    #third-tab {
      position: absolute;
      top: 300px;
      left: 10px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: yellow;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="first-tab"></div>
  <div id="second-tab"></div>
  <div id="third-tab"></div>
  <script>

   function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044}
    });

    var contentString = [];
    contentString[0] = '<div id="content">'+
    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
    '</div>'+
    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
    '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
    'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
    'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
    'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
    '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
    'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
    'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
    'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
    'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
    'Heritage Site.</p>'+
    '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
    '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
    '</div>'+
    '</div>';

    contentString[1] = '<div id="content">'+
    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
    '</div>'+
    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">New York</h1>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
    '<p><b>New York</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
    'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
    'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
    'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
    '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
    'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
    'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
    'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
    'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
    'Heritage Site.</p>'+
    '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
    '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
    '</div>'+
    '</div>';



    var markers = [];

    locations = [{lat: -24.363, lng: 131.044}, {lat: -20.363, lng: 136.044}, {lat: -25.363, lng: 118.044}, {lat: -27.363, lng: 138.044}, {lat: -28.363, lng: 130.044}];
    titles = ['rock', 'Alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'neta'];


    for (var i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
      markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: locations[i],
        map: map,
        title: titles[i],
        mytype: 1
      });
    }

    for (var k = 4; k >= 3; k--) {
      markers[k] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: locations[k],
        map: map,
        title: titles[k],
        mytype: 0
      });
    }

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


          function myclosure(j) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(contentString[j]);
              infowindow.open(markers[j].get('map'), markers[j]);
            }
          }
          for (var j = 4; j >= 0; j--) {     
              markers[j].addListener('click', myclosure(j) );    
         }





    document.getElementById("second-tab").addEventListener('click', function() {

      for (var i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
      }
      for (var i = 4; i >= 3; i--) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
      }
    });

    document.getElementById("first-tab").addEventListener('click', function() {
      for (var i = 4; i >= 3; i--) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
      }
      for (var i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
      }
    });
    document.getElementById("third-tab").addEventListener('click', function() {
      for (var i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
      }

    });   

}
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBga3chd-auBMGLGITc3rjact16mozcI4Q&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the error `markers[j] isn't defined` in the line including the event listener. If instead of loop I manually do the following:

```
              markers[0].addListener('click', function(){
               infowindow.setContent(contentString[0]);
              infowindow.open(markers[0].get('map'), markers[0]);
});
```

Then the infowindow on marker[0] works fine. So,

> Why isn't myclosure function working as expected?

**Edit:** It has been suggested that rather calling the function `myclosure` inside the event listener I should use the event listener inside an immediately invoked function. But why doesn't my method work? I tried the same approach on simple dom elements and it worked. Here is the code I tried:

```js
var cont = document.getElementById("container");

function myclosure(i){
    return function(){
      alert("test" + i);
    }
  }

    for (var i = 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cont.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].addEventListener("click",myclosure(i) );
    }
```

```css
 * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }    
    #container {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #ffff12;
    }
    .one, .two {
      padding: 10px;
      }
    .one {
      background-color: #777;
    }
    .two {
      background-color: #aaa;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
      <div class="one">first</div>
      <div class="two">second</div>
    </div>
```

I have used exactly the same approach as I used with google maps.

> Why is this code working but not the google map code?

Answer (score 2):

In this section

```
for (var j = 4; i >= 0; i--) { 
      markers[j].addListener('click', myclosure(j) );
}
```

You are invoking `myclosure()` and therefore passing what is returned as the handler, not the function itself

try

```
for (var j = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
  (function(j) {
    markers[j].addListener('click', function() {
      myclosure(j);
    });
  })(j);
}
```

Comment: I tried this too now. But it still doesn't work. I even added `alert(j)` in `myclosure(j)` function.

Comment: create a demo that reproduces problem

Comment: By the way does `myclosure(J)` in `markers[j].addListener('click', myclosure(j) )` get executed and the result gets assigned to the event listener or is, just the definition of the function is assigned?

Comment: Because using `()` invokes a function. You can do `addListener('click', myclosure )` but the arguments won't be what you want

Comment: I have made this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pgqLjvjf/ But I could not add the google api key. Can you add this script `<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBga3chd-auBMGLGITc3rjact16mozcI4Q&callback=initMap">
</script>` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any situation where this code :

```
for (j in ) { 
          markers[j].addListener('click', myclosure(j) );
     }
```

can run. In order to work correctly it must be something like

```
for (j in markers) { 
          markers[j].addListener('click', myclosure(j) );
     }
```

There is several other methods that you can use to loop through an array. If you encounter some problems with [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) you can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), designed to loop through arrays.

Comment: can you make a fiddle with the isolated part of the code which is causing trouble please ?

Comment: I don't know how to add google api script in jsfiddle. You can save the whole code as html file and run it.

Comment: I don't encounter any error when testing the whole code you posted. Have you any problem when trying this one directly ? You may have not posted the exact same code but this one seems functionnal on Chrome and FF.

Comment: The infowindow doesn't show. I want them to be shown. I get the error `markers[j] isn't defined`.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I noticed.

1. Scope binding w.r.t `addListener()` call in the loop:

   ```
   for (var j = 4; j >= 0; j--) {
     markers[j].addListener('click', function() {
        myclosure(j);
     });
   }
   ```

   You are trying to access `j` inside your eventHandler callback function. **This eventHandler will get executed only when you'll click on the marker**. In that case, `j` will be -1 as the context has changed. to fix this, following is what you may do.

   ```
   for (var j = 4; j >= 0; j--) {
     markers[j].idx = j;
     markers[j].addListener('click', (function() {
       myclosure(this.idx);
     }).bind(markers[j]));
   }
   ```

   Add the index value to the `marker[j]` as a property and bind it to the eventHandler. This'll ensure that the correct value is used at runtime. But if you don't want to mutate `marker[j]`, then you may do the above as this as well:

   ```
   for (var j = 4; j >= 0; j--) {
     markers[j].addListener('click', (function() {
       myclosure(this);
     }).bind(j));
   }
   ```
2. Above changes are still half way there to get your `myclosure(j)` to work. **`myclosure(j)` is returning a function that never gets invoked :)** To Fix this, your final code shall look similar to this.

   ```
   function myclosure(j) {
     return function() {
       infowindow.setContent(contentString[j]);
       infowindow.open(markers[j].get('map'), markers[j]);
     };
   }

   for (var j = 4; j >= 0; j--) {
     markers[j].addListener('click', (function() {
       myclosure(this)();
     }).bind(j));
   }
   ```

   To make it even simple, you may rewrite above as:

   ```
   function myclosure(j) {
     return function() {
       infowindow.setContent(contentString[j]);
       infowindow.open(markers[j].get('map'), markers[j]);
     };
   }

   for (var j = 4; j >= 0; j--) {
     markers[j].addListener('click', myclosure(j));
   }
   ```

   In this case, we're **calling `myclosure()` in the context with `j` being a valid value**. Since `addListener()` expects a `function` to be binded as eventHandler, we bind the function returned by `myclosure(j)`. The returned function will gets executed in the scope provided by `myclosure(j)` at the time of marker click, where `j` is valid as a result of the immediate invokation of `myclosure(j)` in the loop.

I hope that clarifies your doubt about closure execution.

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vipul_me/pgqLjvjf/3/) I had to change the `initMap()` execution as in JSFiddle I was having trouble to execute it as a callback parameter to the map api call.

Comment: 1. I never used `for (var j = 4; j >= 0; j--) {
  markers[j].addListener('click', function() {
     myclosure(j);
  });
}`  2. The working fiddle you have linked uses the same code as in my question. 3. It seems like my code was always correct; it is working now in my browser. There would have been some back end or server problem.

Comment: Oh Boy! Ye I noticed in your question that you **are** using `myclosure(j)` call already. My Bad to explain it in that detail, but I took your fiddle code only to explain the changes that I made. So the `markers[j]` is undefined can only happen if that array was never having any value assigned to it

Comment: I just thought you are asking about the explanation that why one thing is working & why the other one is not. Anyways if this is no longer a problem, mark the question completed. By posting your own answer & accepting it.

Comment: Also, check the original [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgqLjvjf/) that you shared

Comment: I think rather answering the question myself the question be better deleted as it is already downvoted. Moreover there is nothing to answer because the closure I used was correct. Anyways thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JQuery you can simply add class to each marker with unique ID attributes and add click event listner using class selector.

```
`$(".marker").on("click",function(){
   var _id = $(this).attr('id');
   $(_id+"_infobox").show();
});`
```

Now using id you can insert or open that particular info box.